# jasmine test with a token interceptor

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm creating a unit test into my http interceptor.

What it does is depending on something include a header with the token.

The interceptor:

```
  private requestWithToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, token: string): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>  {
const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)});
return next.handle(authReq);
}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
//logic to get the token
const token = haveToken ? 'tokenValue' : '';
if(token) {
  return this.requestWithToken(req, next, token);
} else {
  return next.handle(req);
}
}
```

And the test:

```
    it('it should include token', () => {

  //arrange
  httpRequestSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpRequest', ['mockedUrl']);
  httpHandlerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpHandler', ['handle']);
  httpHandlerSpy.handle.and.returnValue(of({}));
  //whatever to have token in the test
  //act
  service.intercept(httpRequestSpy, httpHandlerSpy)
      .subscribe(res => {
          //test validation
      });
});
```

the problem is it raised an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
```

when doing this:

```
headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)}
```

I dont understand the error, as req is an httpRequest and should have headers (or at least I think so)

How can I solve?